# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord: has_many and sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My `entry` model has many counters:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :counters
end
```

Every `counter` has a `number`, and the `total` represents the sum of the `numbers`:

```
class Counter < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :total, sum(:number)
end
```

I need to get the sum of all the numbers of the counters which belong to a specific entry.

In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT SUM(`number`) AS `total` FROM `counters` WHERE `entry_id` = entry.id
```

I tried:

```
entry.counters.total
```

But it returns:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `default_scoped?' for 0:Fixnum

Is there any "Rails way" to do this nicely with ActiveRecord associations and scopes?

Comment: Did you mean to say entry.counters.total ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the call to `sum` happens straightaway, ie your code is equivalent to

```
scope :total, 0
```

(assuming that the sum is 0 at the moment that your class is 0), which isn't valid

Fundamentally scopes are about scoping a result set : adding conditions, order, limit or options such as joins, but with the constant that the result is a collection of active record objects.

What you want to do is best expressed as a class method:

```
def self.total
  sum(:number)
end
```

You can still chain this onto a scope, for example

```
some_entry.counters.total
```